# Programmatically open Windows 10 Battery Flyout

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10

I want my application (written in C#) to open the Windows 10 battery/power flyout (see below). I have searched the internet for answers or other implementations, without any success.

I am suspecting it has something to do with `ShellExperienceHost.exe`, as the flyout window itself belongs to that process and also there is a DLL named `BatteryFlyoutExperience.dll` in the same folder, although that only exports two functions:

```
DllCanUnloadNow
DllGetActivationFactory
```

As I am not very good with reverse-engineering unmanaged assemblies, it is unfortunately out of my comfort zone to decompile `ShellExperienceHost.exe` and peek inside.

Now my question, has anyone else found a possibility to open said flyout from C# code (P/Invoke is totally fine)?

By the way, this is the flyout I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: Microsoft has become better over the years in ensuring that there are no APIs available for developers to do this sort of thing, documented or otherwise, as their trust is invariably always abused by people [angling for a bonus](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061101-03/?p=29153). You can retrieve battery status yourself through things like the `Win32_Battery` WMI class, or programmatically open settings pages through appropriate shortcuts (`ms-settings:powersleep`), depending on why you feel you need to show this, but you should leave the poor shell UI alone.

Comment: Use UI Automation (which corresponds to what a real user can do) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview You can check what's possible with the API before writing any code, using the Inspect tool from the Windows SDK.

Comment: What do you need to do with Windows 10 Battery Flyout? Or just simply pop up the Windows 10 Battery Flyout?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT I just want to pop up the battery flyout

Comment: This may not be possible, because the operation of opening and closing the battery pop-up window should be done by the user.